# Complex ordering of a django model

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have a model like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    good = models.BooleanField()
    votes_up = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    votes_down = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    ...
```

I want to select the questions with good = True and order them by (# of votes_up) - (# of votes_down). Is there an easy way of doing this using the Django db functions or the objects methods?

Answer (score 0):

No. You'll have to use [`.extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) in order to specify your fancy pants ordering.